# Extract from (a word) to (another word) in a string using REGEX

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract an entire piece of text using a REGEX expression, but i can't find the right syntax.

For Example this can be my string (that comes from .read):

```
Here there are some stuff that can be whatever

Run:   55 / 100

Here there are some stuff that can be whatever

DOCKED: ENDMDL

Here there are some stuff that can be whatever
```

I want to extract from "Run:" to "ENDMDL"

So for now I'm arrived here:

```
with open("docking.txt","r") as f:
    new_content = f.read()
    pattern_tot = r'(\w{3}\W\s{3})(\d+)(\s/\s)(\d\d)(.+)(DOCKED:\sENDMDL)'
    pattern_2 = r'(\w{3}\W\s{3})(\d+)(\s/\s)(\d\d)'
    
    for i in re.finditer(pattern_2,new_content):
        print(i)
```

The ouput is:

```
<re.Match object; span=(6242, 6255), match='Run:   1 / 10'>
<re.Match object; span=(10453, 10466), match='Run:   2 / 10'>
<re.Match object; span=(14664, 14677), match='Run:   3 / 10'>
<re.Match object; span=(18875, 18888), match='Run:   4 / 10'>
<re.Match object; span=(23086, 23099), match='Run:   5 / 10'>

<re.Match object; span=(423401, 423416), match='Run:   100 / 10'>
```

With pattern_2 i do have the right output (see above).
If i use pattern_tot, it just does not return me anything.

I understood that the problem is somewhere in the pattern_tot regex expression `r'(\w{3}\W\s{3})(\d+)(\s/\s)(\d\d)(.+)(DOCKED:\sENDMDL)'` (probably `(.+)`). I don't really know what to use instead.

Comment: If you want to match from "Run:", how come your current regex does not have "Run" in it? Seems like the rules are different? Also, your code does nothing with `pattern_tot`... so why are you looking for a problem in *that* regex?

Comment: Maybe like this without capture groups `(?s)^\w{3}:[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n]*/[^\S\n]*\d+\n.*?\nDOCKED: ENDMDL\b` https://regex101.com/r/rnj1U2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird i haven't really understood the syntax, but it does not look working

Comment: @RiccardoFusco You  to extract from "Run:" to "ENDMDL" which is what the pattern does for the example data. Why does it not work?

Comment: Try this pattern ```^R.*\s+H.*\s+D.*```

Comment: If you want capture groups `(?s)^(\w{3}:)[^\S\n]*(\d+)[^\S\n]*/[^\S\n]*(\d+)\n(.*?)\n(DOCKED: ENDMDL)\b` See  https://regex101.com/r/MXuhoo/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it look correct also in the website but still does not work, maybe i should use another encoder? Can be possible? https://regex101.com/r/MXuhoo/1

Comment: @RiccardoFusco Can you update the https://regex101.com/r/MXuhoo/1 link with the actual text that you are using? The text in `docking.txt`

Comment: The regex works, the code is wrong, i had to add MULTILINE. Thank you, very helpful!!!! https://regex101.com/r/h06hGg/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` method by providing the pattern to match your case for finding the substring between two strings, then it will return list of all matches in a string:

```
import re
str = "Here there are some stuff that can be whatever1\
Run:   55 / 100\
Here there are some stuff that can be whatever2\
DOCKED: ENDMDL \
Here there are some stuff that can be whatever3\
Run:   80 / 100\
Here there are some stuff that can be whatever4\
DOCKED: ENDMDL "
matches = re.findall('Run:(.*?)ENDMDL', str)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['   55 / 100 Here there are some stuff that can be whatever2DOCKED: ', '   80 / 100 Here there are some stuff that can be whatever4DOCKED: ']
```

In your case when reading a text file you should enable `re.DOTALL` flag to match also newlines in the pattern:

```
re.findall('Run:(.*?)ENDMDL', str, re.DOTALL)
```

**Update:**

You could also define function to find string between 2 strings

```
def find_between2str(start, end, text):
    return re.findall(f'{start}(.*?){end}', text, re.DOTALL)

matches = find_between2str("Run:", "ENDMDL", str)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very pythonic way to do so and it can return very useful!